# How to add a line to BoxAndWhiskerChart?

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

Using JFreeChart I'd like to add a straight line to a BoxAndWhiskerChart, so that the result looks like this:

```
7  |  -   - 
6  |  x       -
5  |      x   x
4  |  -   -  
3  |          -
2  |------------  <- ?
1  |
0  +------------
      A   B   C
```

This is essentially my code for creating the chart:

```
DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset();
//adding data to dataset...
BoxAndWhiskerRenderer rnd = new BoxAndWhiskerRenderer(); 
CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(dataset, x, y, rnd);
JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(plot);
```

Is there a simple way to add a line to the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - You need to add a Marger to the Range Axis.  You can find an example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartMarkerDemo1.htm)

Try adding this code:

```java
final Marker valueMarker= new ValueMarker(2.0);
valueMarker.setPaint(Color.green);
plot.addRangeMarker(valueMarker);
```